# Jquery $.get cannot get it to work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying $.get function to get response from a php script.But no success.

Noting is happening.Here is my jquery code.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
    $('#button').click(function(e){
    var values='key:1024';

    $.get('pro.php',values,

            function income(data){
            alert('something happen);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Here #button is the id of a button in my HTML

No alert box appears.
Now i tried to put a counter kind of thing in my php script that can find how many times script is executed.when i go to my file from browser the counter inceeases but it dose not increase if i click the button 3 or even four times.so i guess the script is not receving the request.or maybe this not how i can check if my script is executed by an ajax request. If so how can i check this?

So whats wrong with my jquery.

Is showing an alert box right to check if a response is received from server side.

Comment: this it invalid js - it has syntax errors, even the markup shows it

Comment: Always check your error console.

Comment: Can you please tell a few mistakes if there are many.as an example

Answer (score 0):

You miss a single qoute in the alert message

So instead of this:

```
alert('something happen);
```

Do this:

```
alert('something happen');
```

Below your code but changed so you can copy paste.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('#butt').click(function(e){
  var values='key:1024';

  $.get('pro.php',values,

          function income(data){
          alert('something happen');
          }
      );
   });
});
```

Please use your console to check if you have any errors because you can find this very easy.

Answer (score 0):

You only missed the single quotes in alert.

```
$(document).ready(
function(){
  $('#butt').click(function(e){
  var values='key:1024';

  $.get('pro.php',values,

          function income(data){
          alert('something happen');
          }
      );
   });
});
```

Add firebug if you are using firefox, it is a very good plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a single quote as the others mentioned and you should also pass your value as an object to be able to easily retrieve it in your PHP file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#butt').click(function(e){

        $.get('pro.php', {
            'key': 1024
        },
        function income(data) {
            alert('something happen');
        });
    });
});
```

To get the value in your PHP file, use:

```
$_GET["key"];
```

Comment: I know the php part well. Was not sure about the jquery part.:-(

Answer (score 0):

```
        //A valid JSON should be 
         var  values = {"key":1024}
         $.get('pro.php',values,function(resp){     });
```

Comment: Okay.I wrote it like that in my firt attemp actually but editing the same file made it like that.i guess it was some other mistake at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys adding a closing quote fixed it even my counter is working now.thanks for your help.And i'll make sure to check my syntax in firebug next time.I have actually heard about firebug but never used it.:-)